# Light and outlet switches pigtailed?

Tags: electrical

[image]

Looking for help to understand why the 2 blacks from 2 different cables and white from a third cable are pigtailed together. The light switch and outlet switch operate independently so why are they together?

Comment: Can you please include a better picture on the inside of that switch box?

Comment: It looks like someone tried bootlegging something so we would need to know more about where the cables go. It looks like 4 blacks and a white on that crimp. I hope it was covered with tape, a white used in a switch leg would be correct for an always hot but figuring out where every thing goes is the challenge here.

Comment: Do you have an electrical tester? What type? With that white wire connected to what appears to be a black hots you need to test for switched neutrals or other reversal issues.

Comment: Can you post photos that look into the back of the switch box please?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.